# Returning two values from method using queries

Tags: java

I have 2 tables `User` and `Role`, `RoleId` is a foreign key in `User` table, 
so I wrote a method here but it is not returning the output I want. I want to count both how many `User` for example have `RoleId = 1` and how many have `RoleId = 2`:

```
public int countPersonelAdminandWorker() throws PerdoruesiException {
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT COUNT(RoleID) FROM User p WHERE p.roleID = 1 ");

    try {
        return query.getSingleResut();
    }
    catch(NoResultException e) {
        throw new PerdoruesiException("...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Google for `group by`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a method that returns array.

```
public int[] countPersonelAdminandWorker() throws PerdoruesiException{
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT COUNT(RoleID) from User p where p.roleID = 1 ");
        Query queryForWorker = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT COUNT(RoleID) from User p where p.roleID = 2");

        try{
            return new int[]{(int)query.getSingleResult(),(int)queryForWorker.getSingleResult()};
        }catch(NoResultException e){
            throw new PerdoruesiException("...");
        }


    }
```

Comment: Are you and "TheFlash" one and the same person?

Answer (score 3):

`"SELECT COUNT(RoleID) as 'Count Role ID' , roleID FROM User p WHERE p.roleID = 1 OR p.roleID=2 GROUP BY p.roleID";`

Comment: jobayserozib , the code wont work if you want to count both of RoleId 1 and RoleId 2.

Comment: Why ? Could you please explain.

Comment: Your code is fing but it will count Users that have RoleId1 or RoleId 2 , the point was to count how many User have RoleID1 and how many have RoleId2.

Comment: That's why i use `GROUP BY` This will separate RoleID1 and RoleID2

Comment: @Dreni: how is your answer better than this one, as this is the much more standard and robust way to solve the original poster's problem?

Comment: @Dreni: and again are you and "TheFlash" one and the same person? Something strange going on here.